# 16 bit word lc-3 BR and JMP instruction

Tags: lc3

I have a issue that I cannot seem to figure out, when it comes to 16 bit words. Below i have attached the corresponding code and the the imagine that gives a bit of a description of what I am asking help for.

```
 .orig x3000
 ld r1,n
 lea r5,data
 add r1,r1,#-1
loop:
 str r1,r5,0
 add r5,r5,r2
 add r1,r1,#-1
 brp loop
 trap x25
data: .blkw 2
n: .fill 10
 .end
```

Here is the image [image]

I get the nzp codes but im not sure how to calculate the pcoffset9 so it would be greatly appreciated if someone could help with this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula to calculate the PCOffset is as follows

ADDRESS_OF_SYMBOL - (INSTRUCTION_ADDRESS + 1)

```
.orig x3000
  LEA R0, HELLO_WORLD                ; x3000
  PUTS                               ; x3001
  HALT                               ; x3002
  HELLO_WORLD .stringz "HELLO WORLD" ; x3003
.end
```

so the PCOffset in the LEA instruction is as follows

ADDRESS_HELLO_WORLD - (ADDRESS_LEA + 1)

x3003 - (x3000 + 1) = 2

When the LEA instruction executes remember that the PC is already incremented as part of Fetch so PC will be at x3001.  We add the 2 to it to get x3003 the address of where the label HELLO_WORLD is.

Comment: Hey Thanks alot, I was wondering if the same logic would apply to a JMP instruction as well? @Brandon

Comment: JMP instructions don't have a PCOffset.  So no.  Maybe you are thinking of the JSR instruction which in that case yes.

Comment: So with the example I provided above I got 0000 001 000000001 as the assembles bits, would that be correct?

Comment: No

I would recommend using an lc-3 simulator, most will show you what the binary for a given instruction will be.